# Should I Force UEFI mode

Tags: kubuntu, uefi, 15.10

I have a Lenovo computer equipped with Win8.1. I'm trying to install Kubuntu 15.10 when the following message appeared:

> "force UEFI installation?...this machine's firmware has started the
>   installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may exist operating
>   systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode"...If you
>   wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability
>   to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force that
>   here......".

When I've chosen Continue button or Go back button, I've got the same page "disk setup" where I can customize disk partitions. All partitions are displayed properly.

Can I continue without having problems with the two OS?

Comment: Best to know details: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Pre-installed Windows is always UEFI, but if you re-installed or had it repaired it may not still be UEFI. And if Windows is UEFI, you want Kubuntu in UEFI boot mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, i would check my BIOS to see if you have Safeboot enabled.
I think you would not get  this warning if this is turned off.

Press F1 at boot, enter BIOS and disable safeboot.

Run the installation again.

Comment: there is no option for safeboot. I have got : boot mode = Legacy support. Boot Priority = UEFI first. USB boot = Enabled. PXE Boot to LAN = Enabled.

Comment: That option is not on the same page. I think its at the end with save and exit. Can you please have a look? I could restart my server and look but id rather not. And please have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: I've changed only Boot Priority to Legacy first.  And worked perfectly. Thanks.